# In Beamer, a label not on the first overlay is not written to the .aux file

Tags: beamer, labels, overlays

The following Beamer document is ridiculous, but demonstrates a problem I encountered in real-world code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\only<2>{
\begin{enumerate}
\item<2>\label{label}
\end{enumerate}
\ref{label}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If the overlay specifications `<2>` are changed to `<1>`, then this (ludicrous) document behaves as expected.  However, with the overlay specification `<2>`, the label `{label}` is never written to the `.aux` file.

How do I label and reference material that does not appear in the first overlay of a frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the problem by making sure that the content does exist on the first overlay and is just not visible, e.g. by using `\visible<2>{}` instead of `\only<2>{}`.

If this does not work for your real document (e.g. because of spacing etc), you could also use `\label` with an overlay specification to make sure it is issued on the correct overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=test]
\only<2>{
\begin{enumerate}
\item<2>\label<2>{label}
\end{enumerate}
ref \ref{label}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\label` with an overlay specification seems like bizarre semantics to me, but, well, even if true, that's Beamer's fault, not yours!  Thanks!

Comment: @LSpice The purpose of the overlay spec in the label is that if you use it in hyperlinks, you can control to which slide in the frame you want to jump to.

Comment: [That](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650778/in-beamer-a-label-not-on-the-first-overlay-is-not-written-to-the-aux-file/650786#comment1623019_650786) makes more sense, thanks!